# How to check if CD drive is open or closed in linux?

Tags: c++, c, linux, cd-drive

I'm making an application that requires the knowledge of whether a CD drive is open or closed.

`eject` opens the CD drive, and checks how long it takes to open (a shorter amount of time says it's open, and a longer, well...), but I cannot use this technique, because the application actually opens the drive (and I do not want to re-open the drive if it's closed, neither do I want to close the drive if it is open).

How would I do this on linux? I saw that it is possible to do this under Windows (might be wrong though), but I haven't seen a way of doing this on linux.

If it's not possible using linux API calls, is it possible to implement a low-level function that could do this?

Comment: I'm not sure this is possible. I don't believe that the IDE interface exposes the state of the drive tray, SATA might though. Also, what about slot and caddy drives that don't have any concept of being open or close?

Comment: @Dai, I wonder then how linux can detect when a CD has been put in the drive then... if I knew that, maybe that could answer my question.

Comment: The drive does notify the system when the media changes, but that's not the same thing as the status of the tray.

Comment: @Dai, oh... quite disappointing :/ Oh well, I guess my question is solved then :(

Comment: There must be ioctl() controlling the opening/closing behaviour , do check the driver of the cd-drive , to find out if any such ioctl exists , ps: I think , this question is better suited for [unix and linux](http://unix.stackexchange.com/questions)

Comment: @BarathBushan, thanks, I will repost it there, but AFAICS, there is no `ioctl()` switch to find if it's open or not. I _do_ know how to open/close it, if that's what you meant.

Comment: @MiJyn [ioctl](http://man7.org/linux/man-pages/man2/ioctl.2.html) is not a switch , it is a system call to the driver , to obtain the status or configure the device

Comment: @BarathBushan, I'm sorry, yes, that's what I meant (I'm bad with terminology, sorry)

Comment: @Dai You are quire correct that slot and caddy drives have no concept of being open or closed - but they do say if there is no disc or if the disc is ok. Check my answer.

Comment: @MiJyn You can do just about anything with `ioctl`, you just need to know where to look for the commands :D

Answer (score 8, accepted):

To make the example code work, you should do it this way:

```
#include <sys/ioctl.h>
#include <linux/cdrom.h>

int result=ioctl(fd, CDROM_DRIVE_STATUS, CDSL_NONE);

switch(result) {
  case CDS_NO_INFO: ... break;
  case CDS_NO_DISC: ... break;
  case CDS_TRAY_OPEN: ... break;
  case CDS_DRIVE_NOT_READY: ... break;
  case CDS_DISC_OK: ... break;
  default: /* error */
}
```

i.e. the result is returned as ioctl() function result, not into slot argument.

Comment: Is there a reason to use CDSL_NONE? The doc says "Slot number to be tested, always zero except for jukeboxes."

Comment: Invoking this ioctl causes the tray to be loaded; is there a way to prevent that?

Comment: @Jason Open the device on non-blocking mode (`O_NONBLOCK`). See [this comment in `linux/cdrom.h`](https://github.com/torvalds/linux/blob/v4.17/include/uapi/linux/cdrom.h#L26).

Answer (score 6):

You can get tray state by using the `CDROM_DRIVE_STATUS` ioctl. All ioctls for CD-drives can be found in `/usr/include/linux/cdrom.h`

```
#define CDROM_DRIVE_STATUS      0x5326  /* Get tray position, etc. */
```

Taken from [here](http://www.mjmwired.net/kernel/Documentation/ioctl/cdrom.txt)

```
int slot;
ioctl(fd, CDROM_DRIVE_STATUS, slot);

switch(slot) {
  case CDS_NO_INFO: ... break;
  case CDS_NO_DISC: ... break;
  case CDS_TRAY_OPEN: ... break;
  case CDS_DRIVE_NOT_READY: ... break;
  case CDS_DISC_OK: ... break;
  default: /* error */
}
```

Comment: Interesting: `CDS_TRAY_OPEN`, there's our answer.

Comment: Doesn't work :/ Here is my source code: http://pastebin.com/y48ZYZ8x . It just returns false, regardless if it's open or not

Comment: If you add debug output for the other variables, which do you get?

Comment: @fredrik, What do you mean by debug output?

Comment: The simplest debug output would be a `fprintf(stdout, "...\n");` for C or `std::cout << "..." << std::endl;`for C++

Comment: @fredrik, sorry, I meant, what do you want me to print? `slot`?

Comment: Something which lets you know which slot it returned, so that you can determine what your computer thinks the CD is doing.

Comment: @fredrik, thanks, I figured out the issue. I used "switched" `slot` instead of the return value of `ioctl`

Comment: Interesting, the page I picked it from ([here](http://www.mjmwired.net/kernel/Documentation/ioctl/cdrom.txt#682)), used slot and not the return value. Seems like an error in the documentation

Comment: @fredrik, yeah, and the "int slot" without any pointers or default value doesn't seem good either...